# android spinner - how do I remove the current selection?

Tags: android, spinner, selection

I have some dependencies between my spinners and it happens, that a spinner becomes empty.

The problem now is, that I don't know how to clear the spinner, I'm adopting the data of the adapter, notify the adapter and if I click the spinner, there are no values in there, but the spinner's selected item is NOT cleared and still is displayed...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you want, but to delete all itens in your spinner you can set the adapter null, like this:

```
mySpinner.setAdapter(null);
```

and if you want to remove a specific item, then you should remove it from your adapter and set your spinner again

```
mySpinner.setAdapter(myAdapter);
```

Comment: thanks, settig to null helps... although, the spinner should not display an value if `adapter.getCount() == 0`...